# Negative RNA virus

Tags: genetics

I have tried to see how this works but I can't find any helpful information. How can a negative strand RNA virus make protein during an infection?

Comment: Then you did not search enough. It took me 2 google searches to find that the virus uses RNA dependent RNA polymerase to convert -ve sense RNA to +ve sense mRNA. Also the virus particle itself contains the polymerase. Link - https://microbiologybytes.wordpress.com/2008/02/04/negative-sense-rna-viruses/